# CakePHP: getting a value from remote JSON file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying to get a specific value (the first value of 'EndDate') from a remote JSON file.

My JSON looks like this:

```
<AssetEntitlementData>
<AssetEntitlement>
    <EndDate>2016-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
    <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
    <ItemNumber>995-1933</ItemNumber>
    <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
</AssetEntitlement>
<AssetEntitlement>
    <EndDate>2016-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
    <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
    <ItemNumber>995-2093</ItemNumber>
</AssetEntitlement>
<AssetEntitlement>
    <EndDate>2014-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
    <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
    <ItemNumber>995-0923</ItemNumber>
    <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
</AssetEntitlement>
<AssetEntitlement>
    <EndDate>2014-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
    <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
    <ItemNumber>995-1553</ItemNumber>
    <ServiceLevelCode>TS</ServiceLevelCode>
</AssetEntitlement>
</AssetEntitlementData>
</AssetEntitlementData>
```

This is my code:

```
<?php 
     $tag = '11111111';
     $apikey='XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
     $url= 'https://example.com';
     $data = array('ID'=> $tag);
     $format = 'json';
     $options = array(
          'http' => array(
          'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
               ."apikey : 5c1e4f40-8094-4719-9995-7475572d2efa\r\n"
               . "Accept : application/$format",
               'method'  => 'POST',
               'content' => http_build_query($data),
               )
          );
          $context  = stream_context_create($options);
          $result = file_get_contents($url1, false, $context);
          if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ 
                    }

          var_dump($result);
          if($format == 'json')
          {
              $response = json_decode($result);
          }

          var_dump($result->EndDate);
         echo "END";
?>
```

Trying:

```
var_dump($response->EndDate);
```

I got: Notice (8): Undefined property: stdClass::$EndDate

Trying:

```
var_dump($response['EndDate']);
```

I got an error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.

[image]

The output for: `die($result);`

[image]

Comment: response from service is not json, it is xml formatted and you can not use json_decode function

Comment: I tried this: before: `$format = 'xml'; ..........  if($format == 'json')
                                {$response = json_encode($result);}
                                elseif ($format == 'xml')
                                {$response = new SimpleXMLElement($result);}`
and it did not work.

Comment: if you sure you get json response you should use $response->EndDate

Comment: If you want to access it as array, you should set assoc flag to TRUE.
`$response = json_decode($result, true);`

Comment: @ubuntux I tried both: `$response = json_decode($result, true);` and `$response = json_encode($result, true);`. I got this: 
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @mbenjemaa, your response data is not in JSON format it is XML like what @Metalik said. If you want to convert it to JSON you should do:
`$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);`, then convert it to JSON:
`$json = json_encode($xml);` then decode it to access as object:
`$response = json_decode($json);`, or as associative array:
`$response = json_decode($json, true);`.

try to dump the value of `$response` after `json_decode()` with and without the assoc flag to see the difference:
`var_dump($response);`

Comment: @ubuntux I tried : `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result); $json = json_encode($xml); $response = json_decode($json); var_dump($response);` and I got 2 warnings: `Warning (2): simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found` -- `Warning (2): simplexml_load_string() [<a href='http://php.net/function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: {&quot;AssetWarrantyResponse&quot;:[],&quot;InvalidFormatAssets&quot;:{&quot;BadAssets&quot;:[&quot;n/a 09&quot;]},&quot;Inva`

Comment: @mbenjemaa, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @Metalik said, your response data is not JSON, it is XML. If you want to access your data as XML object, use `simplexml_load_string()`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

And to get the first value of `EndDate`:

```
var_dump((string)$xml->AssetEntitlement[0]->EndDate);
```

To access your data as JSON object, convert the `$xml` to JSON string then to JSON object:

```
$json = json_encode($xml); // To JSON string
$response = json_decode($json); // To JSON object
```

...to get the first value of `EndDate` from the JSON object:

```
var_dump($response->AssetEntitlement[0]->EndDate);
```

To access your data as associative array, convert the `$xml` to JSON string then to associative array:

```
$json = json_encode($xml); // To JSON string
$response = json_decode($json, true); // To associative array
```

...to get the first value of `EndDate` from the array:

```
var_dump($response['AssetEntitlement'][0]['EndDate']);
```

Lastly, your response data seemed to be missing an end tag for `AssetEntitlementData`. It should be:

```
<AssetEntitlementData>
    <AssetEntitlement>
        <EndDate>2016-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
        <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
        <ItemNumber>995-1933</ItemNumber>
        <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
    </AssetEntitlement>
    <AssetEntitlement>
        <EndDate>2016-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
        <EntitlementType>EXTENDED</EntitlementType>
        <ItemNumber>995-2093</ItemNumber>
    </AssetEntitlement>
    <AssetEntitlement>
        <EndDate>2014-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
        <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
        <ItemNumber>995-0923</ItemNumber>
        <ServiceLevelCode>ND</ServiceLevelCode>
    </AssetEntitlement>
    <AssetEntitlement>
        <EndDate>2014-03-18T23:59:59</EndDate>
        <EntitlementType>INITIAL</EntitlementType>
        <ItemNumber>995-1553</ItemNumber>
        <ServiceLevelCode>TS</ServiceLevelCode>
    </AssetEntitlement>
</AssetEntitlementData>
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get errors: in `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);`: `Warning (2): simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found` -- `Warning (2): simplexml_load_string() [<a href='http://php.net/function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: {&quot;AssetWarrantyResponse&quot;:[],&quot;InvalidFormatAssets&quot;:{&quot;BadAssets&quot;:[&quot;n/a 09&quot;]},&quot;Inva` -- in `var_dump($response->AssetEntitlement[0]->EndDate);` : `Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the XML fiie, in my question.

Comment: could you paste the output of `die($result);`? seems like a bad markup on the response data.

Comment: I put a screenshot for die($result) in my question.

Comment: I tried XML instead of JSON. the $xml variable shows the contents correctly. But I still get an error for var_dump((string)$xml->AssetEntitlement[0]->EndDate);-- I got: Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object – mbenjemaa 10 mins ago

Comment: I tried `var_dump($xml->AssetWarrantyResponse);` and I got a structured output as seen in this image: [link](https://imgur.com/K7hld9m)

Comment: got it:                                     $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
                                    $xml = Xml::toArray($xml);
                                    $end_date = $xml['AssetWarrantyDTO']['AssetWarrantyResponse']['AssetWarrantyResponse']['AssetEntitlementData']['AssetEntitlement'][0]['EndDate'];
                                    debug('EndDate:'.$end_date);